# Circulating through number list

Tags: java, modulo

How can I circulate numbers in java so that

1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=1, 5=2, 6=3, 7=1 , etc.

thus containing an unlimited set of numbers within a limited set of possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

```
public int modulo(int a, int b) {
    int r = a % b;
    return r==0?b:r;
}

assert(modulo(1,3) == 1)
assert(modulo(2,3) == 2)
assert(modulo(3,3) == 3)
assert(modulo(4,3) == 1)
assert(modulo(5,3) == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) 18:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.cycle;
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.limit;
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;

System.out.println(newArrayList(limit(cycle(1, 2, 3), 7)));
// [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```